# How can I insert the Calendar plugins?

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I have installed the WordPress Calendar plugins, and I'd like (in some point of the page) add this plugins, without add the default Calendar to a widget and call this widget to the page (such as `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ); ?>`).

I mean, like to use `SidebarEventsList()` for the **WP Events Calendar Plugins**

How can I do it? Which method I need to call?

Tried with

```
<? {CALENDAR} ?>
```

as the readme.txt says, but I get an error *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'*

Comment: You can't use a WP shortcode within PHP. WP shortcodes need to be inside the content, where WP's filters will parse them and call the appropriate functions. You will need to call those functions directly. Which ones those are, the docs should tell you (or, sometimes, looking into the plugin)

Comment: I thought it, but in fact I don't find it...! Where can I found that WP filters? So I'll check with function call that CALENDAR shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) where ever you want you do this:

Where `CALENDAR` is your shortcode. Just add the shortcode in here like you would in the wp-admin.
Attributes are also allowed.