# How to enable image on RSS generated by wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to add the tag  on rss generated by Wordpress (http://www.myblog.com/rss) that take the first attached image for each post.

How can I do it?

Tried to download/install these :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rss-images/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-image-feed/

but nothing change to the generated RSS!

## EDIT

Tried this solution, after some suggestions :

```
add_action('rss2_item', 'add_images_to_rss');
function add_images_to_rss() {  
    ?>
    <my_meta_value><?php echo "prova" ?></my_meta_value>
    <?php
}
```

still I don't see any changes in the RSS source...

Comment: Do you want an rss feed of `tag` to have the images of the posts? Or do you want to include the featured images to your post feed?

Comment: I see some RSS contains tag `<image>http://http://www.myblog.com/images/attach.jpg</image>` with the link of the image! This is what I need to include in the rss...

Comment: Ahh, that's not impossible. *loading*

Comment: Uhm? Yeah, I've seen this on some RSS, in some blogs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
// add the <image> to the rss and rss2 feed
function SO13586900_add_image_to_rss() {
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
    if ( ! empty( $thumb_id ) ) {
        echo '<image>' . wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id ) . '</image>';
    }
}
add_action('rss2_item', 'SO13586900_add_image_to_rss');
add_action('rss_item', 'SO13586900_add_image_to_rss');
```

Tested and works

Comment: Uhm, not clear what do you suggest to me! I think I'll wait for the complete answer! Don't forget it :)

Comment: Tried, but nothing happens! Check my update question with example :O

Comment: ill get back to you in roughly 2 hours. try `add_action('rss_item'`, instead of `add_action('rss2_item',`

Comment: Found a way : edit the `feed-rss2-php` files adding my custom tags! Thank you anyway!

Comment: its bad practise to edit core files. you might lose your edits when updating. and it isn't that hard to do what you want

Comment: On which "functions.php" I need to add this code? into my template?

Comment: yes in the theme/YOUR-THEME folder. if you are new to WP you should say so. setting 4k rep points I assume you know at least a bit about WP

Comment: Not really :) I'm not so involved in WP, honestly I don't like it at all :)

Comment: I see that, after inspecting your profile. I love it, especially from a user-friendly-ness view point.

Comment: I'm working on a web agency with home-made cms! WordPress is terrible if you have to edit somethings! Also because I don't like so much PHP :P

Comment: I understand your issues, although I don't agree. PS I also anwered an other Wordpress question of your which was ope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671952/how-can-i-insert-the-calendar-plugins/13606440#13606440

Comment: @janw is this code valid after installing something else to wp website? I have pasted it into theme/functions.php and it did not change anything?

Comment: @zkanoca It should. Did you inspect the real XML of the rss? The posts do have featured images? I havn't used this in a while. but it should work

Comment: @janw my mistake. I have seen it. Great!